# MongoDB crashing due to missing collection*.wt file

Tags: mongodb, centos7, wiredtiger

Similar threads are present on SO and other forums, however my issue seems to be different in that I can start mongod and read from it successfully. When running the command 'show dbs' in the mongosh terminal, it returns an error saying:

```
MongoServerError: unable to open cursor at URI statistics:table:collection-124-8620454490016200065. reason: No such file or directory
```

Also, when trying to write large amount of data to the db it the mongod service itself crashes due to missing .wt files. The mongod.log file says:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-02-28T12:11:51.031+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"conn26124","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":2,"message":"[1646030511:31871][2824:0x7f3c0e85e700], file:collection-102-8620454490016200065.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: __posix_open_file, 805: /var/lib/mongo/collection-102-8620454490016200065.wt: handle-open: open: No such file or directory"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-02-28T12:11:51.036+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":50883,   "ctx":"conn26124","msg":"Cursor not found","attr":{"error":{"code":43,"codeName":"CursorNotFound","errmsg":"Failed to open a WiredTiger cursor. Reason: UnknownError: 2: No such file or directory, uri: table:collection-102-8620454490016200065, config: "}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-02-28T12:11:51.037+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"conn26124","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":50883,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_cursor.cpp","line":72}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-02-28T12:11:51.037+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"conn26124","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

I assume one collection is missing from the db. I have no means to verify this. Data loss for any corrupted data is not an issue. Just need to get the db working again.

Update: as suggested in the comments, mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair worked as expected. Although it seems some collections were lost from one of the dbs. Good reminder for backups!

Comment: good time to try to repair with: mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair
( but backup the /data/db first )

Comment: Might as well try that. Curious as to why this would happen though. Can an unexpected system reboot cause this?